pipenv does not use or not working with an older version of Python
I need to use Python 3.7 and so I created a virtual environment with the following command - pipenv shell --python 3.7. And when I try to execute the pipenv lock command, I get the following error - RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
My Pipfile:
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
python_full_version = "3.7.0"

Here's the full traceback:
PS D:\freelance\apb-master\flaskdir>pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2024.1.0
PS D:\freelance\apb-master\flaskdir>python -V
Python 3.7.0
PS D:\freelance\apb-master\flaskdir>pipenv lock --verbose 
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mihaj/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 6, in <module>
    from functools import cached_property
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'functools' (C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\functools.py)
Locking Failed!
[    ] Locking dev-packages...
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    # when invoked as python -m pip <command>
                 ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\options.py", line 52, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 342, in lock
    do_lock(
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\routines\lock.py", line 67, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 859, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 723, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!

I also tried using an older version of pipenv, but it doesn't work either.

What exact steps did you go through to create the environment? Did you start with that Pipfile already in the project folder when  you created the virtual environment, or use an existing requirements.txt, or did you create the virtual environment and then run pipenv install flask?   The error message would indicate the Pipfile.lock file is locked by another process, but reading reports of similar error message reports online this sounds like it a could be a sub-dependency issue, possibly related to flask only supporting back to Python 3.8 unless you force an older version install.

Note that dependency resolution failed first, because functools.cached_property doesn't exist in Python 3.7. It's not clear why pipenv tries to continue after that failure.

@nigh_anxiety, Thanks! I already had a pipfile and pipfile.lock  files in my project. I created a venv with python version that specified in pipfile and I wanted to update some packages  using pipenv update.

Note pipenv==2023.10.20 dropped python3.7 https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/releases/tag/v2023.10.20 . I mean when you tried an older pipenv version, you wouldn't be completely safe unless used something previous to that release.
